# Make Error's message property enumerable

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make the Error object's "message" property enumerable so that when you stringify it:

```
var errstr = JSON.stringify(new Error('my error'));
```

so that it gives you `{"message":"my error"}` instead of `{}`

I know you could do that for each individual object

```
var err = new Error('my error');
Object.defineProperty(err, 'message', {
  enumerable: true,
});
var errstr = JSON.stringify(err);
//=> {"message":"my error"}
```

but is it possible to do it to the `Error` object itself so you don't have to do it to each of its instances?

Comment: Maybe you could define `Error.prototype.toJSON`.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: With ES6 Classes it's much easier to just define a custom Error object:

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  toJSON(){
    return JSON.stringify({
      message: this.message
    })
  }
}
```

Also modifying native objects wasn't such a great idea.

---

Old answer:

Welp, I figured I could change `JSON.stringify` itself, if not the `Error`

```
(function() {
    var stringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Error)
            Object.defineProperty(obj, 'message', {
                enumerable: true,
            });
        return stringify(obj);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who puts properties other than `message` on their Error objects and wants them to JSON.stringify correctly too:

```
class JsonableError extends Error {
    toJSON() {
        return JSON.stringify(Object.assign({ message: this.message }, this));
    }
}
```

or even (if you want to construct your errors using a JSON object):

```
class JsonObjectError extends Error {
    constructor(input) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, input);
    }
}
```

Then you can do `new JsonObjectError({ "message": "foo", "something": "else" })` and it stringifies correctly.  This second version even makes `message` an enumerable property of the `Error` object.