# How to catch the error and res.send the error message to the clientside by using Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js

Trying to catch to Error after using Node.js to search data from the database. However, the server always sends {errormsg: null} to the client side when there is an error happened.
I expect that there will be a detailed explanation in the errormsg json.

```
router.get('/testing', (req, res) => { 
    var db = req.db;
    var col = db.get('collection'); 

    col.find({})
    .then((docs) => {res.json(docs);})
    .catch((error) => {res.json({errormsg:error});
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many properties of an error object are not enumerable and thus will not show in JSON (yes, this is often a pain).

You can see that for yourself if you just run this simple nodejs program:

```
try {
    throw new Error("stuff happened");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

It will just log `{}` because the properties you are interested in within the  Error object are not enumerable and `JSON.stringify()` only grabs enumerable properties.

You can either grab the specific properties you want, put them into a new plain object as enumerable properties like this:

```
router.get('/testing', (req, res) => { 
    var db = req.db;
    var col = db.get('collection'); 

    col.find({})
    .then((docs) => {res.json(docs);})
    .catch((error) => {
        const result = {};
        result.message = error.message;
        result.stack = error.stack;
        res.json({errormsg: result});
    }); 
});
```

Or, you can write yourself a function that will enumerate the non-enumerable properties and copy them to an object as enumerable properties that `JSON.stringify()` will then include.

```
function makeVisibleError(src) {
    const result = {};
    for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)) {
        result[prop] = src[prop];
    }
    return result;
}

router.get('/testing', (req, res) => { 
    var db = req.db;
    var col = db.get('collection'); 

    col.find({})
    .then((docs) => {res.json(docs);})
    .catch((error) => {
        const result = makeVisibleError(error);
        res.json({errormsg: result});
    }); 
});
```

In a real-world application, you probably don't want to pass everything from the raw error object back to the client, so you would select one or more properties manually or make your own message.

---

FYI, if you make your own Error subclass, you can override the `toJSON()` method and select specific properties for inclusion.  See [Make Error's message property enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561454/make-errors-message-property-enumerable) for more info.